# Arithmetic with variables

Tags: bash, scripts, tcsh

I am trying to do arithmetic as I assign a variable a value. When the script reaches end_day it cannot do the math, and when I test it in the terminal it will simply return the expression. What do I need to do to get a result assigned to the variables.

Here is part of the script, `$fhour` comes from elsewhere and is simply a two digit number.

```
#Date variables
export start_year=$(date -u +%Y)
export start_mon=$(date -u +%m)
export start_day=$(date -u +%d)
export start_hour=$fhour
export end_year=$(date -u +%Y)
export end_mon=$(date -u +%m)
export end_day=${$start_day+(((($start_day*24)+84)/24)-((($start_day*24)+84)%24))}
export end_hour=${($start_day*24+84)%24}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the guide of *Cyberciti* for [bash arithmetic](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Perform_arithmetic_operations) you are not using the correct method. To make arithmetics operations this is the format:

> $((expression))

So in your case this would be the right variable assignment:

```
export end_day=$(( $start_day+(((($start_day*24)+84)/24)-((($start_day*24)+84)%24)) ))
export end_hour=$(( ($start_day*24+84)%24 ))
```

---

*NOTE: this need to be tested, not sure if results are correct.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that fixed the arithmetic problem.. I think. The rest of the script is showing its errors now, but that debugging is for another day.

Comment: +1 nicely done.  I was working on this one too, but you beat me to it!